# MongoDB collection.save() duplicating objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, nosql

I'm working on my first web dev project involving backend work, and i'm giving mongoDB a shot. I'm currently working on a simple admin panel where every user is listed, and by clicking on that user the admin can go in and manually edit their info, update, and return to the master user list to see the changes.

I'm trying to use the `collection.save()` method to update the existing users, but I've encountered a problem where, instead of just updating, it creates a duplicate copy of the document with a matching `_id` number. Here is an [image](http://imgur.com/ZShMwem) illustrating what I mean, and here is all of my code for the update:

```
router.post('/updateUser', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = req.collection;

var userId = req.body.userId;
var djStatus = req.body.djStatus;
var access = req.body.access;
var firstName = req.body.firstName;
var lastName = req.body.lastName;
var email = req.body.email;
var phone = req.body.phone;
var studentStatus = req.body.studentStatus;
var macIdNum = req.body.macIdNum;
var iclass = req.body.iclass;
var gradYear = req.body.gradYear;
var show = req.body.show;
var blurb = req.body.blurb;

collection.save(
{
    _id: userId,
    djStatus: djStatus,
    access: access,
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    studentStatus: studentStatus,
    macIdNum: macIdNum,
    iclass: iclass,
    gradYear: gradYear,
    show: show,
    blurb: blurb
}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        res.send('there was a problem updating');
    } else {
        console.log(doc + ' doc');
        res.location('admin/users');
        res.redirect('admin/users');
    }
});
```

});

I am really not sure why this is happening. any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you perform a find() via mongo shell showing these documents? There is a unique index on _id which should not allow duplicates.

Comment: yes i can. they are duplicated in the shell too which is very confusing to me. thought the _Id was supposed to prevent that:

Comment: Can you post the shell output as well as the output of db.collection.getIndexes() where collection is your collection name?

Comment: [shell output image](http://imgur.com/anQSp3O) looking at the output more carefully i can see that the problem is that the update isn't converting the _id to an ObjectId. how do i make that happen?

Comment: try:  _id = new ObjectID(userId)

Comment: what's the syntax for doing that with mongoskin? their docs are pretty vague: https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin#collectionupdatebyidid-

i was trying to just have _id as another field, so `collection.updateById(_id:userId, firstName: firstName)` etc as their docs imply, but that returns an error.

Comment: See the following page - it looks like mongoskin provides a helper for the conversion: https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/blob/eef60a1ca83a0ecf1bdafc2a70044cfee407da39/lib/helper.js

Comment: fyi: this answer helped me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713565/mongodb-nodejs-mongoskin-update-not-working

Answer (score 0):

From the post, I'm not sure which mongodb driver you're using but save() is probably not used for updating a document in mongodb.  There should be an update() function from the mongodb driver you are using.  For example, with mongoskin driver, this is the syntax for insert/update:

```
collection.update(_id: userId, {$set: data}, {safe:true, upsert:true}, function (err, result) {
  // check err and result and do something
});
```

Comment: save() can be used to update if you plan to replace the entire document.